# If I compile java with javac do I need JVM?

Tags: java, jvm, javac

I recently learned about how Java uses the JVM to make itself platform independent and I often write code and compile it with the `javac` command in terminal (Mac OS X). So my question is whether `javac` compiles it for JVM or if it is compiled directly to machine code? which would make it platform dependent.

Comment: `javac` produces Java class files, which is run on the JVM.

Comment: post it as an answer, with a a bit more detail/explanation and I will accept it.

Comment: Yes, in the general case you need a JVM.  Most standard Mac/Windows boxes will have a version of the JVM installed, though not always a version new enough for your compile "target".  A standard compiled Java program is not platform-dependent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The java compiler (javac) produces bytecode from source code. This bytecode is the instruction set of the JVM. It is run on the JVM so whilst the bytecode is platform independent, the JVM is not.